# How can one hide / show an input-group in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to hide / show a Bootstrap 5 `input-group` as shown here:

https://jsfiddle.net/o08r3p9u

However, once hidden, the input group no longer shows correctly when shown again. How can this functionality be properly implemented?

```js
function dotoggle() {
  elem = document.getElementById("hideme")
  if (elem.style.display == "none") {
    elem.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    elem.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-group mb-3" id="hideme">
  <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>

<button onclick="dotoggle()">
BUTTON
</button>
```

Comment: simplest solution :just add a parent element which can have display block & toggle that . bootstrap uses flex which is why it is arranging to block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the div `#hideme` uses the `flex` display (`.input-group` class), but in the jquery code you specify the `elem.style.display = "block";`. And this is not correct.

In the `jquery` code, specify the `elem.style.display = "flex";`, like here:

```js
function dotoggle() {
  elem = document.getElementById("hideme")
  if (elem.style.display == "none") {
    elem.style.display = "flex";
  } else {
    elem.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-group mb-3" id="hideme">
  <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>

<button onclick="dotoggle()">
BUTTON
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap has own tools to hide and show the elements: [Collapse](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/collapse/).

Therefore you can use layout, classes and data-attributes from documentation, and Bootstrap does all work itself. For example:

```html
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="input-group mb-3" id="hideme">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
  </div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Button
</button>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok to solve this simply add another container around the `input-group` `div` and run the same function you had on the new main container `div`.

Here check the JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cv8oazym/7/

Answer (score 0):

It is from the javascript written.
You are setting the display to "block" when re-rendering the input.
Set display to "flex"

```js
function dotoggle() {
  elem = document.getElementById("hideme")
  if (elem.style.display == "none") {
    elem.style.display = "flex";
  } else {
    elem.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript is applying a *display: block* instead of a *display: inline-flex*.

So at start the input-group is set to display: **inline-flex**, then set to display: **none** but then is changed to **block** instead.

```
function dotoggle() {
  elem = document.getElementById("hideme")
  if (elem.style.display == "none") {
    elem.style.display = "inline-flex";
  } else {
    elem.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using collapse class of bootstrap , therefore no additional JS required from our side.

Thus a complete bootstrap only solution.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="input-group mb-3 collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>

<button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
BUTTON
</button>
```